# Website redirect in HTML5 video playing issue

Tags: html, redirect

everyone.  I get a problem in website link redirect in HTML5 video playing issue.

The idea is I have video playing and I just want to click the icon then redirect to other page by javascript.

I use XAMPP windows version.  There is no problem in testing in IE, Firefox, and chrome.  When I switch to Google Chrome Cloud service in Ubuntu 18.04 (also use XAMPP linux version), Firefox is ok but IE and chrome will show "Waiting for ......" message but will not do the link redirect.

https://35.230.33.231/users/x/